# Notation on $ n > \pi(n) $, as $n$ grows, the difference grows

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, notation

Let $\pi$ be the prime counting function, and $n$ a positive integer greater than 3.

I would like to express in a math paper that that $ n > \pi(n) $ and as $n$ grows, the difference is getting bigger.

What is the correct notation for that?

Comment: Do you know about limits ?  Asymptotic notation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (n-\pi(n))=\infty$$ ?

Comment: or $n\notin O(\pi(n))$

Comment: We could also say $$n-\pi(n)=O(n)$$ or $n-\pi(n)$~$n$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$, but this does not well emphasize the difference.